# Always getting 'Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded' with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js

Good morning,

I am currently learning how to drive Selenium with javascript (using mocha). I created a really basic test that is giving me a lot of trouble at runtime. Whenever I run the test a new instance of chrome is created and the browser displays. When the browser initially comes up it places "data:," in the URL box then proceeds to google.com. I then get the following error back:

$ mocha test

```
  Array
    #indexOf()
      ✓ should return -1 when the value is not present! 

  Google Search
    1) should work


  1 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Google Search should work:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:157:19)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

Here is the test itself:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

test.describe('Google Search', function() {
  test.it('should work', function() {
    var chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
    chromeOptions.addArguments(['test-type']);

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeOptions.toCapabilities()).build();

    driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
    driver.wait(function() {
     return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {  
       return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
       });
    }, 1000);
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message you get looks like a Mocha timeout to me. The normal way to set a timeout in Mocha is:

```
it("foo", function () {
    this.timeout(value);
    ...
});
```

where `value` is whatever value you want (in ms). A value of 0 turns off Mocha's timeouts. The default is 2000ms.

Answer (score 0):

IF it fail somewhere in particular consistently maybe you should be considering calling `driver.Manage().Timeouts()`.

`ImplicitlyWait()` doesn't actually wait like a `Thread.sleep()` does, it just sets the drivers maximum wait time for implicit waits. Just calling it once at the start of your code (with 20 second parameter passed in) is sufficient. Read up on *ImplicitlyWait* and the *WebDriverWait* class.

As far as I remember (when I had to used) this is caused because you don't get the response in the expected/by default time.