# Understanding enableTimeouts

Tags: javascript, timeout, mocha.js

In [`mocha` 1.21.0](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/HISTORY.md#1210--2014-07-23), a new setting was introduced `enableTimeouts` (true/false); and a corresponding `--no-timeouts` command-line argument.

The problem is, *it is not documented*.

Which use cases does it cover? When can it be useful to disable the timeouts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mocha has supported turning off timeouts for a long time. Using [`timeout(0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26146193/1906307) also disables timeouts. What `enableTimeouts()` allows which `timeout()` did not is to turn timeouts off and on without forgetting what the timeout used to be before it was turned off. For instance:

```
describe("foo", function () {
    this.timeout(500);

    describe("no timeout", function () {
        this.enableTimeouts(false);

        it("without a timeout", function (done) {
            setTimeout(done, 1000);
        });

        describe("timeout", function () {
            this.enableTimeouts(true);
            // From this point on, we are back to a timeout of 500ms.

            it("with a timeout", function (done) {
                setTimeout(done, 1000);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I've disabled timeouts while designing tests because I may not right away know what a good limit is going to be. So while I'm working on the test, the timeout is disabled, and then I reenable it with a reasonable value.

I've not encountered a case where I've *had* to disable a timeout permanently so that the test suite would work.

Comment: Wow, never thought of it this way! Thank you for the help again!